# Moving the last column to the first position in a matrix - Impact on determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found an T/F question where we are basically asked if moving the last column to the first position in **any** matrix results in the determinant of said matrix changing.

This was False and as an explanation it said that in any "matrix with an **odd** number n of rows or columns this operation corresponds to switching two colums n-1 times. This gives an even number of sign changes, so the determinant changes by a factor of (-1)^n-1 = 1 (n-1 always even number) and hence does not change."

I don't understand how this makes any sense. Column swaps should break the relations between rows and therefore result in a completely different matrix. This would only make sense if we were talking about row swaps, in which case every times this operation happens the determinant of the matrix is multiplied with -1.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the determinant of a matrix and of its transpose are the same

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however performing this operation on a matrix won't generally result in its transpose.

Comment: If you take the transpose, swap two rows, and take the transpose again... then you've swapped two columns.

Comment: Moving the first column as first is not a swap (transposition) but a cycle - and odd cycles are even permutations, so the sign doesn't change. For example, changing 123 to 312.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I understand now!